# What does a number followed by " in" mean?

Tags: highlighting, lengths, vim, syntax

The TeX syntax highlighter that I use colors all occurrences of a number followed by " in", e.g. `0 in` or `32 in` in a dangerous bright red, in almost all contexts. Why?

Comment: Probably it interprets this as "32 inches". What editor are you using?

Comment: @egreg: vim and the syntax files that came with it for Ubuntu 11.10. You seem to be right by the way: it also highlights "32 pt", "32 em" and "32in".

Comment: @egreg: That's a solid *answer* to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know about Vim and its TeX/LaTeX syntax parser. It probably uses some rule that interprets a number followed by one of the keywords `in` `pt` `cm` `mm` `em` `ex` (and maybe also the other units of measure accepted by TeX) as denoting lengths; this is usually good, but it fails in situations such as

> There are 42 books on the shelf and still 32 in the box

My flavor of Emacs+AUCTeX (Aquamacs) doesn't do this: it highlights lengths only in the argument of `\setlength` and `\addtolength`.